# correctly use of sendSubview(toBack: ) function in swift

Tags: ios, swift

with this lines of code, i want to create a new `UIView` behind of `UILabel`. but it does not work.
myNewView always become over headerTitleLabel while i want it be behind label.
what can i do?

```
    let myNewView = UIView()
    myNewView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.815, green: 0.956, blue: 0.941, alpha: 1)
    myNewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.headerTitleLabel.addSubview(myNewView)
    self.headerTitleLabel.sendSubview(toBack: myNewView)

    myNewView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.headerTitleLabel.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myNewView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.headerTitleLabel.centerYAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
    myNewView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.headerTitleLabel.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.08, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myNewView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.headerTitleLabel.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.7, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: You need to use `self.view.insertSubview(view: myNewView, belowSubview: self.headerTitleLabel)` instead.

Comment: no, i have many UILabel in project and i want add extension to UILabel to change any of UILabel i want. with this method i should have "self.view", but i don't want

Comment: But `sendSubView(toBack)` works with its `superView` not with its siblings.

Comment: so how can i create a view in a UILabel and send it back?

Comment: `self.headerTitleLabel.superView.insertSubview(view: myNewView, belowSubview: self.headerTitleLabel)` by this way.

Comment: correct! please post it and i check it true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `insertSubView(view: ,belowSubView:)` method instead.
You can add `myNewView` on `headerTitleLabel`'s `superView`.

```
self.headerTitleLabel.superView.insertSubview(view: myNewView, belowSubview: self.headerTitleLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it may help you.

Add the `myNewView` in `main view`.

```
self.view.addSubview(myNewView)
```

Then add the `label` in the `myNewView`.

```
 myNewView.addSubview(headerTitleLabel)
```

It may helps you. Thank you.

Comment: in above comments i described why i can't use this method